# Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'WingtipToys.Logic.ShoppingCartUpdate[]' is less accessible than method

Tags: c#, asp.net

Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'WingtipToys.Logic.ShoppingCartUpdate[]' is less accessible than method 'WingtipToys.Logic.ShoppingCartActions.UpdateShoppingCartDatabase(string, WingtipToys.Logic.ShoppingCartUpdate[])'   C:\Users\Toshiba\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WingtipToys\WingtipToys\Logic\ShoppingCartActions.cs 93  21  WingtipToys

I don't understand the error please help.
The code where error is showing is in the first line of the given code UpdateShoppingCartDatabase.

```
namespace WingtipToys.Logic
{
    public class ShoppingCartActions : IDisposable
    {
        public string ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
        private ProductContext _db = new ProductContext();
        public const string CartSessionKey = "CartId";
        public void AddToCart(int id)
        {
            // Retrieve the product from the database.
            ShoppingCartId = GetCartId();
            var cartItem = _db.ShoppingCartItems.SingleOrDefault(
                c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId && c.ProductId == id);
            if (cartItem == null)
            {
                // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists.
                cartItem = new CartItem
                {
                    ItemId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    ProductId = id,
                    CartId = ShoppingCartId,
                    Product = _db.Products.SingleOrDefault
                    (p => p.ProductID == id),
                    Quantity = 1,
                    DateCreated = DateTime.Now
                };
                _db.ShoppingCartItems.Add(cartItem);
            }
            else
            {
                // If the item does exist in the cart, 
                // then add one to the quantity.
                cartItem.Quantity++;
            }
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_db != null)
            {
                _db.Dispose();
                _db = null;
            }
        }
        public string GetCartId()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[CartSessionKey] == null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session[CartSessionKey] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    Guid tempCartId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session[CartSessionKey] = tempCartId.ToString();
                }
            }
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[CartSessionKey].ToString();
        }
        public List<CartItem> GetCartItems()
        {
            ShoppingCartId = GetCartId();
            return _db.ShoppingCartItems.Where(
                c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId).ToList();
        }
        public decimal GetTotal()
        {
            ShoppingCartId = GetCartId();
            // Multiply product price by quantity of that product to get 
            // the current price for each of those products in the cart.
            // Sum all product price totals to get the cart total.
            decimal? total = decimal.Zero;
            total = (decimal?)(from cartItems in _db.ShoppingCartItems
                               where cartItems.CartId == ShoppingCartId
                               select (int?)cartItems.Quantity * cartItems.Product.UnitPrice).Sum();
            return total ?? decimal.Zero;
        }
        public ShoppingCartActions GetCart(HttpContext context)
        {
            using (var cart = new ShoppingCartActions())
            {
                cart.ShoppingCartId = cart.GetCartId();
                return cart;
            }
        }
        public void UpdateShoppingCartDatabase(String cardId, ShoppingCartUpdate []
            CartItemUpdates)
        {
            using (var db = new WingtipToys.Models.ProductContext())
                {
                try
                {
                    int CartItemCount = CartItemUpdates.Count();
                    List<CartItem> myCart = GetCartItems();
                    foreach (var cartItem in myCart)
                    {
                        //Iterate through all rows within shopping cart list
                        for(int i = 0; i < CartItemCount; i++)
                        {
                            if (cartItem.Product.ProductID == CartItemUpdates[i].ProductId)
                            {
                                if (CartItemUpdates[i].PurchaseQuantity < 1 ||
                                    CartItemUpdates[i].RemoveItem == true)
                                {
                                    RemoveItem(CartId, cartItem.ProductId);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                  UpdateItem(CartId, cartItem.ProductId, 
                                      CartItemUpdates[i].PurchaseQuantity);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: can you provide the `ShoppingCartUpdate` definition as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to provide more information to get a definite answer.  Like what a `ShoppingCartUpdate` is and how its defined.

As the error message suggests, you have a difference in accessibility.  This could mean that your `ShoppingCartUpdate` is declared `internal` (example) so it can't be used in a public method as something outside of the assembly is allowed to call `UpdateShoppingCartDatabase`, but not allowed to access `ShoppingCartUpdate` as it's marked internal (again example, need more information)